# JAVAFX Scroll pane autoscroll based on event

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scrollpane, pane

Is there a way to make a scroll pane change hvalue and vvalue based on values changing in code , i have an if statement which should change the hval and vval of a scroll bar in javafx when some value changes but the hval and vval are not moving (no scrolling occurs)

```
public void recenter(){
anchorPane.setPrefWidth(anchorPane.getPrefWidth()*2);
anchorPane.setPrefHeight(anchorPane.getPrefHeight()*2);
scrollPane.setHValue(0.5);
}
```

i added the code , its simple , i have an anchor pane as a child of the scroll pane and its exactly fit to its size , when i double the anchor panes size by clicking the recenter button , i want the horizontal scroll to automatically scroll to the middle (hvalue = 0.5) , but it doesnt , it actually scrolls to the middle when i press the button again!! , any idea why??

Comment: Please show us your code that is currently not working, what you tried to fix it, potential error messages, a StackTrace, the results of your own conducted research on the problem and anything else that could be useful to actually help you.

Comment: Those properties can be adjusted using the setters (or a binding or something like this). If this is not working for you, the updates are probably not performed, you apply them to a `ScrollPane` that is not shown on screen or the value you pass to the setters is incorrect. No way to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: i added the code , its simple , i have an anchor pane as a child of the scroll pane and its exactly fit to its size , when i double the anchor panes size by clicking the recenter button , i want the horizontal scroll to automatically scroll to the middle (hvalue = 0.5) , but it doesnt , it actually scrolls to the middle when i press the button again!! , any idea why??